# Security parameter p =O(n)

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

In many homomorphic encryption scheme, a security parameter is calculated as p =O(n).

How to use the complexity order as values?

Is there any specific method with an appropriate example?

Comment: Do you mean how to pick a concrete value of the security parameter $p$? In that case it probably depends very much on the concrete scheme and the state of the art in breaking the underlying computational problem.

Comment: Do you mean how to interpret O(n) as a scalar value?

Comment: @Venkatesan S. Venkatesan  If you reply to the two comments above by editing your question, you will surely get a good response.

Comment: @HilderVitorLimaPereira: Yes